# Extract link from page HTML with Perl

Tags: html, perl

To extract links from HTML pages use the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

open( SITE, "< index.html" );

my $html = <SITE>; # load the HTML file

my $content = 'XML::LibXML'->load_html(string => "index.html", recover => 1);

my @del = qw( Contact Tables );
my $condition = join ' or ', map "text()='$_'", @del;

for my $anch ($content->findnodes("//a[$condition]/..")) {
$anch->parentNode->removeChild($anch);
}
open (NOTEPAD, ">> index.html"); 

print NOTEPAD "$content"; 

close(NOTEPAD);
```

My problem is use the $file variable to read the contents of HTML page, it not work.

If I use the HTML tags inside the $file variable it works. But not is solution.

Comment: There is no `$file` variable. I don't understand your question.

Comment: I'm sorry.
Is variable $html.

Comment: @PHPDeveloper then correct your question

Answer (score 2):

You can `use WWW::Mechanize;` to accomplish your task.

```
my $mech  = WWW::Mechanize->new();

$mech->get( $url );     #url to extract links
my @links = $mech->links();
foreach my $link (@links) {
     my $curr_url = $link->url_abs; 
}
```

For complete documentation of this module refer [WWW::Mechaniize](http://search.cpan.org/~oalders/WWW-Mechanize-1.84/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) (part of [Mojolicious](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious)) which allows you to use CSS selectors, which I feel is a much better approach;

```
use Mojo::DOM;
use Mojo::File qw( path );

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( path('index.html')->slurp );

foreach ( $dom->find('a')->each ) {
    # Do something with $_
}

my $html = $dom->to_string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program opens file `index.html`, reads *one line* of it into `$html`, and then tries to parse the string `index.html` as if it were HTML data

Forget about opening and reading the file; you can get `XML::LibXML` to do all of that for you, with

```
my $content =  XML::LibXML->load_html( location => 'index.html', recover => 1 );
```

Comment: I use open( SITE, "< index.html" );

my $html =  do { 
 local $/; 
 <SITE> 
}; 
But not work good!
Do you have any opinion?

Comment: @Developer: My opinion is that you should try the code I suggested. And please don't just say something "doesn't work"; it gives us no information whatsoever.